# Spring inject array of separate properties

Tags: java, spring

I have few properties in my props file like:

```
productCode1=A
productCode2=B
productCode3=C
```

And I want to inject them to my service class as an array or list, but I can union them to one property like `productCodes=A,B,C` they should be separately because I use them in other places.

In there some annotation for it? Or maybe I can do it somehow with `SpEL`? 
As I understand `@Value` is not suitable here because it takes as a parameter only one string.

Comment: You could create another property like `anotherProperty=${productCode1}, ${productCode2}, ${productCode3}`.